# How to tell if a kinetemic body is not touching the ground?

Tags: gdscript

I'm new to GD script and trying to learn the language.

I'm making a basic character controller. I want to make the game with a double jump feature and don't know how to accomplish this. I have the code below written already.

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const UP = Vector2(0,-1)
var motion = Vector2()
var jumps = 2
var isAddingToJumps = true;

func _physics_process(delta): 
    motion.y += 9.81
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        motion.x = 100
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        motion.x = -100
    else:
        motion.x = 0

    if isAddingToJumps and is_on_floor():
        jumps += 2
        motion.y = 0
        isAddingToJumps = false


    if not is_on_floor():
        isAddingToJumps = true


    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up"):
        if jumps > 0:
            motion.y = -400
            jumps -= 1


    move_and_slide(motion, UP)
```

After some debugging, I think I know the problem with the code. When the object is touching the floor, it thinks it is touching and not touching it at the same time. Is there any easy way to fix this?

I should probably mention as well that the horizontal movement works just fine and when it jumps that works, the program just doesn't know when to jump

Comment: I think a good place to start would be to add an `else` statement to your `("ui_up")` keypress function that specifies what happens if `jumps == 0`.

Comment: I have an if statement inside the `"ui_up"` keypress that checks if `jumps > 0`

Answer (score 0):

When I change `jumps += 2` to `jumps = 2` it will work